# is there a way to use imagemagick or another graphics library to filter and image based on the pixels in another image

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

So I wrote a program to do this, but it takes forever to execute. I've noticed a lot of graphics libraries seem to execute stuff way faster than the things I code. Basically what I want to do is filter the pixels in the first image using the second one. If they don't match replace them with black. I just want to be able to see the wall in the image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What language do you use? Things are slow if you do it pixel by pixel but there are libraries around that handle whole arrays at a time.

Comment: Lol, Java. And yea that was pretty stupid. I did do it pixel by pixel;

Comment: Huh? How can you ever find the wall which is 1286 pixels high in a photo of a building that is 600 pixels tall? Why is one image a lossless PNG and the other a lossy JPEG - they will also never match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick, you can extract the unique (srgb) colors from your image2 after limiting the colors to 255. Then you can loop over each color and have it fill that color with white in the first image and all other colors with black. This makes a mask image, which can be multiplied with image1 to make your result. Adjust the fuzz value as desired.

```
colors=`convert image2.jpg -fuzz 10% +dither -colors 255 -unique-colors txt: | cut -d\  -f6`
list=""
for color in $colors; do
val="-fill white -opaque '$color'"
list="$list $val"
done
eval 'convert image1.png -fuzz 1% '$list' -fill black +opaque white mask.png'
convert image1.png mask.png -compose multiply -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: I've made some progress. I got the script to run by adding \ to the end of the statements, but the image I'm getting back is way less defined. Basically just the center line on the building.

Comment: What is your ImageMagick version, date and platform/OS? Have you used back-ticks in the first command line for colors= and single quotes in the line for eval? Are you using the exact same images that were posted. Note that your second image is JPG and has lossy compression.